# If write to the remote memory over PCIe which marked as WC(Write Combined), then do we have any consistency automatically?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, x86, x86-64, memory-fences

As we know on x86 architecture the **acquire-release consistency provided automatically** - i.e. all operations automatically ordered without any fences, exclude first store and next load operations from different locations. (As said Herb Sutter on page 34: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=4E86B0CF20EF15AD!24884&app=WordPdf&authkey=!AMtj_EflYn2507c )

And as we know when we **write to** the remote **WC-marked memory over FSB**, then CPU uses temporary buffer with size 64 bytes - WCB (Write Combined Buffer)/BIU (Bus Interface Unit). And "When the WCBs are ultimately dumped to external memory over the FSB, data is not necessarily written to memory in the same order in which the earlier programmatic stores were executed." i.e. **we have not the automatically acquire-release consistency** - qutoted from [If we marked memory as WC(Write Combined), then do we have any consistency automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718781/if-we-marked-memory-as-wcwrite-combined-then-do-we-have-any-consistency-autom)
See "WCB FSB Transactions" on page 1080 for more information.

But what will happen if we **write to** the remote **WC-marked memory over PCI Express**, will we have the **automatically acquire-release consistency, when we use MOV or SSE**?

Comment: Why should it matter if the store is sent through FSB or PCIe? The ordering (or lack of it) is maintained within the core, once a WC buffer is dispatched, it already reflects possible reordering

Comment: @Leeor Core of of what? And where is really reordering happen in buffer WCB/BIU or in interface FSB/PCIe? And if reordering can be only in interface, then can be reordering both in FSB and PCIe or only in FSB? In the quote of answer to my previous question - the answer about reordering in WC-marked memory over the FSB is **clearly tied to the FSB** - This requires clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as reordering across different contexts since there's no original order across such writes (aside from anything explicitly maintained by synchronization methods). 
In other words - if core1 and core2 each write a line, these lines can be observed in any order without braking consistency. The prohibition is on different cores observing different orders for these two lines (i.e. core3 sees the line from core1 first, and core4 sees core2 first). Even that is limited to other cores, cores1 and 2 may each see its own write ahead of the global order (this is a relaxation that x86 does compared to sequential consistency, to allow intra-core forwarding).

What can be potentially reordered are stores within a given program context. Here the order does matter of course, so a program doing -

```
     thread 0     |   thread 1
 store [x] <-- 1  |   load [y] 
 store [y] <-- 1  |   load [x]
```

Under the normal x86 memory model (considered to be TSO-like) must preserve that a result of x==0 and y==1 is impossible (assume both were initially zero), since that implies that the stores were reordered. To avoid that, stores will be dispatched in the order maintained by the core's internal queues - even though the execution is done out-of-order, the store may only be seen by the outside world after it is committed (a stage where the reordering buffer restores the original program order). This also guarantees that the store will not be seen if an earlier instruction had an unexpected exception or a branch misprediction.

On the other hand, write-combining allows a more lenient memory ordering model, so stores may be combined and committed whenever the write-combining buffer has the full line. This reduced the bandwidth but allows stores to reorder, for e.g.

```
store [x] <-- ..
store [z] <-- ..
store [x+8] <-- ..
store [x+16] <-- ..
...
```

the 2nd store may be reordered ahead of the 1st, since the 1st will wait for the write-combining buffer to fill up. Once the buffer is full (although there's no enforced limit to that), the line is sent out to memory, regardless of any path it has to travel.

The comment about FSB in that other answer doesn't mean it's specific, it dates back to a Pentium 4 guide, so after passing the last level cache, they just assume you go on the FSB. The terms are different nowadays, but anyway - nobody out there cares about ordering any lines, and as I said - once you're no longer within the core, there's no notion of order, only coherency. They just meant that once the line is out it may be observed, and that's the point where the order breaking becomes visible.

Comment: Thank you! Is this true when Core1 located on CPU1, Core2 located on CPU2, and these CPU1 & CPU2 connected over PCI Express (Non-Transparent Bridge) and communicate via shared memory marked as WC over PCI Express? (not over QPI)

Comment: I'm not familiar with your exact configuration, but if a line coming out of a given core already reflects a reordering of the stores done on that core, there's no way to restore the original order outside of that core (let alone the processor). It's not even possible without breaking the line into the original chunks.

Comment: Thanks. But will be order between two different lines (64 bytes) in this case? If we write line1 and then line2, will we recive it in the same order?

Comment: From 2 different cores / CPUs? not without explicit synchronization (and even that probably won't work on WC the same way as for WB). From the same core? probably not, that's the price of using the weakly-ordered WC. You could try fencing (I think a locked RMW would do that) or explicitly flushing lines to achieve that.

Comment: "flushing lines" - mean `SFENCE` or `CFLUSH`?

Comment: There's a list here of all the ways to explicitly commit WC lines - http://download.intel.com/design/pentiumii/applnots/24442201.pdf (see page 6).